# How can I replicate this behaviour?

Tags: android, layout, android-bottomappbar

I was looking about Material Design and I found the new BottomAppBar in the official page.
I've watched a video about a page behaviour and I wish to replicate it in my app.
I've already added BottomAppBar but I don't know can I find info about that behavior (not the Fap behaviour, the Activity/Fragment opening).

[This](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1KJSld6h82fzkcafrHCDFPOITibpWxF-5%2Fbehavior-layout-primary.mp4) is the video from the official page.

I dont need the code, just some info like the "name" of this behavior or a site where i can learn to use that.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [BottomAppBar](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/) and [MaterialButton](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md) ,

See this article https://www.journaldev.com/21043/android-p-bottomappbar-materialbutton

with little bit of tweaks and animations you can achieve .

Also have a look at this [library](https://github.com/4face-studi0/MaterialBottomBar)

[image]

Comment: I'll edit my question. I dont need the moving Fab, i need open Activity/Fragment behaviour. Thx anyway :)

Comment: For activity transition use  `makeSceneTransitionAnimation`

Comment: so this is just an activity with a different transition animation?

Comment: for fragment https://medium.com/@DeepakDroid/share-element-transition-between-recycler-view-and-fragment-8ce5084fd7a2

Comment: also check http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-4-recyclerview/